# "This looks like spam"

Tags: support, questions, reputation, spam

I have a complex issue. It is a rare issue and has been plaguing me for several years.

Therefore, it needs explaining.

Therefore, it's long - 7237 characters produced over two hours of constant typing.

When I try to submit, I get "This looks like spam" error.

I had a single link, which was important to provide additional context. Since spam usually has links, I removed the link, but I got "This looks like spam".

Is there any way I can submit it (ie. for moderator approval) without magically gaining/grinding/earning through association bonus X reputation points? If yes, is there a way to do so in a way I can still get reputation from it, so I can prove I am a human and not be hit with something similar the next time I have a complex issue?

EDIT: ardaozkal suggests there should be a captcha when I try to submit - unfortunately, there is no captcha, only `Your question couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above.` message.

EDIT 2: Here's the post: http://pastebin.com/CdAM1Mpk (the line `PUT INTO THE TITLE: Overriding mouse drivers to enable left-handed button layout` is a reminder to put a correct title and it doesn't go in the final post, of course). NB that this post also triggered Pastebin's anti-spam filters, but there was a captcha there and I managed to submit it.

EDIT 3: I trimmed the post down to 3668 characters, removed sections with all-caps and game titles, and [it made it through](https://superuser.com/questions/1131346/overriding-mouse-drivers-to-enable-left-handed-button-layout).

I am happy and grateful for all the help I received from commenters. (Once again, thank you!)

However, the original question - ie. what to do when your post is blocked with spam filter - remains unanswered (not counting the implicit "ask people on Meta about it", heh).

I still haven't received any e-mail from the Help Center (it's been only two days), but I will edit the question when I receive the response.

Comment: If it says "this looks like spam", it should ask for captcha iirc.

Comment: Can you post a link to the content of the question? On pastebin or similar?

Comment: Contact SE using the contact us link in the footer, they can adjust the spam filters to allow the post

Comment: @Ferrybig I think I'll try that first.

Comment: @DavidPostill Edited the post.

Comment: @Dragomok I can't spot anything obvious ...

Comment: You've put a lot of time into the question, but let me make a suggestion for when you are able to post it.  It's well written, well organized, and uses good formatting, but it's way too long, so many people won't read it.  Leave out everything non-essential to get the size down.  Ideas: Leave out the terminology section, handle Win-swap with a link.  Leave out all commentary and non-essential words and phrases; just state the facts as directly as possible.  You might be able to leave out the Benchmarks section.

Comment: @fixer1234 This is a good fallback plan - I just thought I'd address the issues that usually came up when I was discussing it elsewhere (I guess I'll edit them back in when they come up). And I admit several paragraphs showcasing how broken gaming mouse can probably be replaced with "due to issues with Razer I have so-and-so rickety setup" without getting comments about "why no gaming mouse" or "your setup is the cause of the problem". If I won't get mail from Help Center, I'll try that.

Comment: @Dragomok - Even if you do get a email response from whomever you emailed, you should still, improve your question.  If your question is not detailed and to the point, people are going to find it confusing, and will vote to illistrate that fact.  Voting is the only way for us as community members to show a question or answer has problems.  If you question contains thousands of words, that is a pretty good indication, your quesiton is simply to confusing and you have yet to identify your actual question or problem.

Comment: @Dragomok: (1) This shouldn’t cause the spam warning, but please don’t use backticks so much.  We use backticks only for code, filenames, things that you type (including config files and scripts) and other things that appear in terminal windows. (2) This shouldn’t cause the spam warning (but it might): please minimize your use of all-caps. (3) I have no idea whether this is related to the spam warning, but try taking out all (or most) of the product and game names, and see whether you can post that.  If that works, try editing them back in.

Comment: @Ramhound edited the post. Thank you for sugestions.

Comment: I just read your pastbin, but I don't see a question, that can be answered

Comment: @Ramhound Title + first line after first header `I want to switch left and right mouse button on the driver level.`. I thought "I want to..." is an accepted alternative to "How can I..." on StackExchange sites?

Comment: @Dragomok - I never said it was.  I was just trying to explain that, if you are not brief but provide the require information people will find your question confusing.  Only so much can be done by leaving a comment that says "your question is confusing".  Was trying to explain how voting works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proven solution to having your question blocked by spam filter is:

- make a post on meta and have meta regulars help you.

However, if you don't have enough reputation to do that, you can do the following:

1. paste the content of your question into an online copy-paste service, like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/),
2. log in to SuperUser,
3. navigate to Help Center page, which currently is behind a **contact us** link should be at the bottom of the page,
4. fill in the form by pasting the link from step 1. and explaining that your question is blocked by spam filter.

The Help Center should eventually respond and give you advice on how to modify your post to bypass the filter, and possibly on how to improve general question quality.

(In my case, spam filter was activated by overuse of two rather innocuous word. I was also told to try and reduce the length of the post "a bit".)

Comment: What were the two "innocuous" words?

Comment: @DavidPostill "game" and "driver". I can understand "game", since pirated game downloads are something of a staple of shady spam ads, but I don't quite get why would spam contain "driver". Illegal racing VoDs? Traps for technically illiterate people with sudden driver problem? (I omitted the filter triggers intentionally, but in retrospect it's not like knowing these two words will help spammers by any significant margin, I guess.)

Comment: Ah. We get a lot of spam for software that supposedly updates/fixes drivers ...